# Partial View not reloading after post update of parent view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a parent view with a dropdown and a table and a child view (partial view) with details related to the items in the parent view.  Double clicking on a parent updates the child view with the children of the parent clicked with an Ajax call.  The dropdown box filters the parent view, and I want to have the children update as if the user double clicked the top row of the parent table.

Here is how the parent view adds the child view:

```
<br><div id="divpartial">

@{
    Html.RenderAction("MeetingDetails", "Meetings", new { id = Model.MeetingID });
}
</div>
```

The ajax call for the double click (which works) is:

```
$("body").on("dblclick", "#meetingList td", function () {
var row = $(this).closest("tr");
//alert("DoubleClick Row "+row.find("td:eq(0)").text());
var MeetingID = Number(row.find("td:eq(0)").text());

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: '@Url.Action("MeetingDetails", "Meetings")',
    data: { "id": MeetingID },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (result) {
        $("#divpartial").html(result);
    }
})
});
```

And here is the dropdown selection action that filters the parent view, with an ajax call after the submit that is essentially the same as the doubleclick call above.  The result for the parent view is correct, but the partial view does not update unless I then double click on a parent row.

```
$('#pid').change(function () {  //Select a project to filter parent table
    document.getElementById('#Pfilter').value = $(this).val();
    $('#meetingsForm').submit(); //<== This works calling the forms controller method to update the parent table showing only items for the selected project
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        updatetargetid: "divpartial",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '@Url.Action("MeetingDetailsFromPID", "Meetings")',
        data: { "pid": $(this).val() },
        dataType: "html",
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        alert(err.Message); //This does not occur so the ajax call is a success
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#divpartial').html(result); // My controller function gets called and builds the correct data into a new model, but the child view never updates.
        }
    })
});
```

And here are my two controller functions (model setup omitted, but debugger validates code omitted is working):

```
public ActionResult MeetingDetails(int? id = null)
{  //Pass in a meeting ID or null
    MeetingDetailsVM detailsVM = new MeetingDetailsVM();
    return PartialView(detailsVM);
}

public ActionResult MeetingDetailsFromPID(int pid)
{  //pass in a project ID and use the first meeting ID for the child view
    MeetingDetailsVM detailsVM = new MeetingDetailsVM();
    return PartialView(detailsVM); // I have a breakpoint on this line to inspect the model, and all is as it should be.
}
```

Comment: I think I am finding errors in the missing controller code.  But also I believe that it is best to have a single controller action handle both cases, so I've added a boolean to allow a single function handle the case where an item was selected from the dropdown vs. just selecting on of the parent elements with a double click.  I will get it working this way and then try again to have two different action result handlers to see if that will work.